# Is there an easy way to reproduce pre-1.8 Adventure gamemode block handling rules in 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft 1.8, the Adventure gamemode is much more configurable than it has been in previous versions. However, by default, players cannot break or place blocks at all. In previous versions, players could break blocks given the proper tool (e.g., a player could break stone if they had a pickaxe), and place blocks freely. Is there a way to reproduce this old behavior in Minecraft 1.8?

Comment: There's really no easy way to do this, precisely, that I can think of. There's definitely no easy way to do this within `/gamemode 2`, since you would need to edit the NBT data of everything ever. I think there's a way to *kind of* do this in survival mode with some command blocks, though. I'll work out a solution tonight if I get the chance.

Comment: Sadly, the new rules in 1.8 are pretty much forced upon us. It would be nice if there was a new NBT tag introduced that would revert the item to classic configurations.

Comment: VTLO. The other question is more recent, and I'm not convinced that it has better answers. Perhaps that one should be closed as a dupe of this one, nor is it clearly stated better (I, for one, prefer the wording used here).

Answer (score 4):

The best way I can think of is to constantly check for and set the relevant `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` tags.

There's only 6 types of tool that will need to be altered, and we can add the `CanPlaceOn` tags to everything since it's the same for all blocks and it doesn't matter if it's on items.

These commands are **very** long though, for example, here's the one to have blocks able to be placed on everything else:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:air","minecraft:stone","minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt","minecraft:cobblestone","minecraft:planks","minecraft:sapling","minecraft:bedrock","minecraft:flowing_water","minecraft:water","minecraft:flowing_lava","minecraft:lava","minecraft:sand","minecraft:gravel","minecraft:gold_ore","minecraft:iron_ore","minecraft:coal_ore","minecraft:log","minecraft:leaves","minecraft:sponge","minecraft:glass","minecraft:lapis_ore","minecraft:lapis_block","minecraft:dispenser","minecraft:sandstone","minecraft:noteblock","minecraft:golden_rail","minecraft:detector_rail","minecraft:sticky_piston","minecraft:web","minecraft:tallgrass","minecraft:deadbush","minecraft:piston","minecraft:piston_head","minecraft:wool","minecraft:piston_extension","minecraft:yellow_flower","minecraft:red_flower","minecraft:brown_mushroom","minecraft:red_mushroom","minecraft:gold_block","minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:double_stone_slab","minecraft:stone_slab","minecraft:brick_block","minecraft:tnt","minecraft:bookshelf","minecraft:mossy_cobblestone","minecraft:obsidian","minecraft:torch","minecraft:fire","minecraft:mob_spawner","minecraft:oak_stairs","minecraft:chest","minecraft:redstone_wire","minecraft:diamond_ore","minecraft:diamond_block","minecraft:crafting_table","minecraft:farmland","minecraft:furnace","minecraft:lit_furnace","minecraft:standing_sign","minecraft:ladder","minecraft:rail","minecraft:stone_stairs","minecraft:wall_sign","minecraft:lever","minecraft:stone_pressure_plate","minecraft:wooden_pressure_plate","minecraft:redstone_ore","minecraft:lit_redstone_ore","minecraft:unlit_redstone_torch","minecraft:redstone_torch","minecraft:stone_button","minecraft:snow_layer","minecraft:ice","minecraft:snow","minecraft:cactus","minecraft:clay","minecraft:jukebox","minecraft:fence","minecraft:pumpkin","minecraft:netherrack","minecraft:soul_sand","minecraft:glowstone","minecraft:portal","minecraft:lit_pumpkin","minecraft:unpowered_repeater","minecraft:powered_repeater","minecraft:stained_glass","minecraft:trapdoor","minecraft:monster_egg","minecraft:stonebrick","minecraft:brown_mushroom_block","minecraft:red_mushroom_block","minecraft:iron_bars","minecraft:glass_pane","minecraft:melon_block","minecraft:pumpkin_stem","minecraft:melon_stem","minecraft:vine","minecraft:fence_gate","minecraft:brick_stairs","minecraft:stone_brick_stairs","minecraft:mycelium","minecraft:waterlily","minecraft:nether_brick","minecraft:nether_brick_fence","minecraft:nether_brick_stairs","minecraft:enchanting_table","minecraft:end_portal","minecraft:end_portal_frame","minecraft:end_stone","minecraft:dragon_egg","minecraft:redstone_lamp","minecraft:lit_redstone_lamp","minecraft:double_wooden_slab","minecraft:wooden_slab","minecraft:cocoa","minecraft:sandstone_stairs","minecraft:emerald_ore","minecraft:ender_chest","minecraft:tripwire_hook","minecraft:tripwire","minecraft:emerald_block","minecraft:spruce_stairs","minecraft:birch_stairs","minecraft:jungle_stairs","minecraft:command_block","minecraft:beacon","minecraft:cobblestone_wall","minecraft:wooden_button","minecraft:anvil","minecraft:trapped_chest","minecraft:light_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:heavy_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:unpowered_comparator","minecraft:powered_comparator","minecraft:daylight_detector","minecraft:redstone_block","minecraft:quartz_ore","minecraft:hopper","minecraft:quartz_block","minecraft:quartz_stairs","minecraft:activator_rail","minecraft:dropper","minecraft:stained_hardened_clay","minecraft:stained_glass_pane","minecraft:log2","minecraft:log2","minecraft:acacia_stairs","minecraft:dark_oak_stairs","minecraft:slime","minecraft:barrier","minecraft:iron_trapdoor","minecraft:prismarine","minecraft:sea_lantern","minecraft:hay_block","minecraft:carpet","minecraft:hardened_clay","minecraft:coal_block","minecraft:packed_ice","minecraft:double_plant","minecraft:prismarine","minecraft:barrier","minecraft:red_sandstone","minecraft:sea_lantern","minecraft:iron_trapdoor"],HideFlags:16}}}
```

(And I may have missed some blocks out)

You'll need to produce similar commands for the behavior you want to add to each of the tool types. Fortunately they'll all be much shorter than this one.

Once you've done that (if it's worth the effort) just put them on any kind of clock. It'll affect all dropped items, so you'll need to throw things you craft onto the floor if you want them to work.

Comment: Is it actually possible to place blocks on air at all, even in survival mode?

Comment: 1.13 syntax for command: `/execute as @e[type=item] run data merge entity @s {Item:{tag:...` -> unfortunately these commands get even longer as new versions of minecraft are released.